# How to call chain of promise functions?

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

I need to call a chain of promises:

```
main(): Promise<any> {
  1) call get();
  2) then `get()` is finished call getTwo()
  3) When `getTwo()` is finished return promise to main() function
}

get(): Promise<any>  {
  //
}

getTwo(): Promise<any>  {
  //
}
```

I tried to demonstrate what I need to do.

Comment: try this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies?

Comment: Promises cannot be called, and neither can a chain of promises. Only functions can be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how promise chain goes :

```
return this.get()
.then(data1 => {
    return this.getTwo(data1);
}).then(data2 => {
    return data2;
})
```

For more details , **[do read](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)**

Shorter version of this could be as @JoeClay's comments

```
this.get().then(this.getTwo)
```

Comment: Note that you can make this slightly terser by making use of implied returns: `this.get().then(data1 => this.getTwo(data1))`

Comment: In fact, you could go even further: `this.get().then(this.getTwo)`

Comment: How to pass variable `finsh` and return this in the end of chain loop as true value?

Comment: @Jessie, just put the return before this.get and you are done

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for

```
main(): Promise<any> {
  return get().then(getTwo);
}
```

Notice that it does not "return promise to main() function" when `getTwo` is finished, but resolves the promise that `then` created and returned immediately.

Comment: Can you extend this example please?

Comment: To what? It does just what the question asked for.